# Authentication on Concurrent Connections in IE

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, kerberos, ntlm

When IE9 visits a HTTPS website, and spans multiple concurrent connections for content downloads, do each of these connections get authenticated on its own?

What I observed so far seems like this:

- IE9 authenticate by NTLM     - NTLM handshake authentication at each concurrent connection
- IE9 authenticate by Kerberos - 1 authentication at primary connection only
- IE7 authenticate by Kerberos - authentication at each concurrent connection

Answer (score 0):

Most of it depends on the server. What is your server?
NTLM always authenticates on connection-level because it requires multiple trips. Kerberos can be authenticated on connection- or request-level. Make sure that you do not have any HTTP sessions involved in your testing.